# I can't making the navigation bar stick to top when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in fronted and I buy and following course from Udemy. 
Maybe problem is because Instructor used bootstrap alpha 4 version, I using alpha 6.

I can't just set up `postion:fixed` for navbar with top of page, my nav bar have 970px margin top, and when I scrolling want to nav be 970px from top and from bottom 971px, and that is problem.
Here is picture of navbar:

[image]

1. index.html file:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   <title>First website</title>
   </head>

   <body>
       <section id="cover">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-3">
                       <div class="lead wall-sticker">
                           we. <br> plant. <br> trees. <br>
                           <a href="#">
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-outline my-2 my-sm-0 text-white">Learn more</button>
                           </a>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-9">
                       <h1 class="moto">For <span class="bold-green">every</span> item sold, we plant 1 tree.<br><br>Want to become a <span class="green-underline">part</span> of it?</h1>
                       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </section>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse" id="main-nav">
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
           <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   ```
2. I have main.js file, there are:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 970) {
         $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       }
       if ($(window).scrollTop() < 971) {
         $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       }
     })
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS sticky?

to stick an element to the top of a page:

`position: -webkit-sticky; 
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;`

Comment: I tried right now, and didn't help, thank you on try to help.